# Android TableLayout issue - Not able to set it correctly

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

Please share the fix for the TableLayout - little confused how to set the weights and columns to arrange the layout as per the needs. I'm hoping you will get the formatting needs based on the layout_span. But will try to explain in words. Putting down how I visualize the layout

1. First row - to have a button spanning across the width
2. Second row - to have the heading center aligned
3. Third row - to have two TextViews taking 50% area each
4. Fourth row - to have the heading center aligned
5. Fifth row - to have one ImageView taking 16.6% of the width and TextView taking the rest 83.3%.
6. Sixth row - to have one ImageView taking 16.6% of the width and TextView taking the rest 83.3%.

Here is the code:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_get_questions"
            android:id="@+id/btnNext"
            android:textColor="@color/windowBackground"
            android:layout_span="4"
            android:layout_column="1"
            />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/app_scoring_leaders"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_span="4"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:padding="5dp"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtDailyScores"
            android:text="1. Kapil Bhagia (34511)\n2. Hardik Bhagia (2231)"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:layout_weight="3"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtAllTimeScores"
            android:text="1. Kapil Bhagia (34511)\n2. Hardik Bhagia (2231)"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:layout_weight="3"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/app_get_started"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_span="4"
            android:padding="5dp"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_assessment_black_36dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_span="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_intro"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:layout_weight="5"/>

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_today_black_36dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_span="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/app_base_score"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:layout_weight="5"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took a little time but there are changes related to layout_weight that I had to do, the entire table structure had to be changed. I used LinearLayout instead for the last two rows. The first four rows could be done using TableLayout. Layout_spans had to be simplified - seems we cannot have complex layouts. Happy to understand if there are better solutions.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_rankgrade"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            />

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp" android:layout_gravity="center">
        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:layout_gravity="center" android:gravity="center" android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/myImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/trframered1"

                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/myImageView"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/myImageView"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/myImageView"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/myImageView"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/myImageViewTextHead"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/app_last_rank_grade"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtLastDayRankGrade"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="-"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/relativelayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:gravity="center" android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/myImageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/trframered1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/myImageView1"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/myImageView1"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/myImageView1"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/myImageView1"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/myImageViewTextHead1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="All Time"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtLastAllTimeRankGrade"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="-"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_get_questions"
            android:id="@+id/btnNext"
            android:textColor="@color/windowBackground"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/app_scoring_leaders"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:padding="5dp"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtDailyScores"
            android:text="1. Kapil Bhagia (34511)\n2. Hardik Bhagia (2231)"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtAllTimeScores"
            android:text="1. Kapil Bhagia (34511)\n2. Hardik Bhagia (2231)"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/app_get_started"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:padding="5dp"/>
    </TableRow>
   </TableLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_assessment_black_36dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/app_intro"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_today_black_36dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="@string/app_base_score"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
```